# Windows 7 session 0 file access

Tags: windows, service, session-0-isolation

I am trying to start an application as a Windows service and that application is designed to modify files and uses network connection too. I have an Administrator account, called 'admin', which can not see local driver, nor network ones. I have tested the following command with PsExec as 'admin' user in session 0:

```
fsutils fsinfo drives
```

The output listed all the drives, but I can not use them at all. Even the 'mkdir', 'cd' basic commands does not work, because the commands can not be found.

The who am I command executed too:

```
whoami /all
```

[image: whoami_result]

There is no entry for using drives. Could you tell me what settings are necessary to use the network and local drives in session 0 with 'admin' account?

Comment: You can't directly run built-in commands such as mkdir via psexec.  Instead, run `cmd.exe` with psexec and then you can use built-in commands as normal (or nearly normal).

Comment: You won't be able to access mapped network drive letters, because those are local to your own session.  But you can map them in the psexec session using command line tools like `net use`.  You don't need to do anything special to use local drives, those are global.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Using cmd.exe solved the problem. Thank you for the answer. :) Now I can reach the local drives and mount the needed ones, so it's awesome.